# How to tranfer selected row data from gridview to TextBoxes when clicking button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, selectedindexchanged

I have created gridview and it will shown as popup gridview.Now, i need to add the button on this gridview to transfer selected row's column values to the TextBoxes when clicking the button (this is similar to OnSelecetedIndexChanged,but i need to use javascript functions).All of these function should use JavaScript functions only.Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

All I can suggest is to do your research. Here's a good place to start: [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com)

Have a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp